# Is there any plugin for VS or program to show type and value etc... of a C# code selection?

Tags: c#

What I want to do is be told the type, value (if there is one at compile-time) and other information (I do not know what I need now) of a selection of an expression.

For example, if I have an expression like

```
int i = unchecked((short)0xFF);
```

selecting 0xFF will give me (Int32, 255), while selecting ((short)0xFF) will give me (Int16, 255), and selecting i will give me (Int32, 255).

Reason why I want such a feature is to be able to verify my assumptions. It's pretty easy to assume that 0xFF is a byte but it is actually an int. I could of course refer to the C# Language Specifications all the time, but I think it's inefficient to have to refer to it everytime I want to check something out. I could also use something like ANTLR but the learning curve is high.

I do intend to read the entire specs and learn ANTLR and about compilers, but that's for later. Right now I wish to have tools to help me get the job done quickly and accurately.

Another case in point:

```
int? i = 0x10;
int? j = null;
int x;
x = (i >> 4) ?? -1;//x=1
x = (j >> 4) ?? -1;//x=-1
```

It may seem easy to you or even natural for the bottom two lines in the code above. (Maybe one should avoid code like these, but that's another story) However, what msdn says about the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is lacking information to tell me that the above code ((i>>4)??) is legal (yet it is, and it is). I had to dig into grammar in the specs to know what's happening:

- null-coalescing-expression
- conditional-or-expression
- conditional-and-expression
- exclusive-or-expression
- and-expression
- equality-expression
- relational-expression
- shift-expression
- shift-expression   right-shift   additive-expression
  ... (and more)

Only after reading so much can I get a satisfactory confirmation that it is valid code and does what I think it does. There should be a much simpler way for the average programmer to verify (not about validity, but whether it behaves as thought or not, and also to satisfy my curiosity) such code without having to dive into *that* canonical manual. It doesn't necessary have to be a VS plugin. Any alternative that is intuitive to use will do just as well.

Comment: You haven't really said why you need to verify your assumptions.  If they are wrong, you'll get a compile error.  That is to say, the compiler is the tool you are looking for.

Comment: @siride: Some of my assumptions involve expressions that won't give a runtime nor compile-time error. The simplest class of problems revolve around integral values and bit shifting, casting, integral literal etc... A wrong assumption can mean a missing sign-extension in an otherwise seemingly innocuous expression.

Comment: @siride Not true if he is casting.  He will only find out at run-time.

Comment: so you are wanting to check for bufferoverflows or underflows?

Comment: @Lucas B: I'm not sure what you meant by bufferoverflow or underflow in this context. In a more general sense, I want to be able to tell if an expression means what I think it means, in a relatively simple way. I'm not quite sure how to further express myself here, maybe because it's too general a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not aware of any add-ins that do what you describe - however, there is a trick you can use figure out the type of an expression (but not the compile-time value):

- Assign the expression to a `var` variable, and hover your mouse over the keyword `var`.

So for example, when you write:

```
var i = unchecked((short)0xFF);
```

and then hover your mouse over the keyword `var`, you get a tooltip that says something like:

> **Struct System.Int16**
>
> Represents a 16-bit signed integer.

This is definitely a bit awkward - since you have to potentially change code to make it work. But in a pinch, it let's you get the compiler to figure out the type of an expression for you.

Keep in mind, this approach doesn't really help you once you start throwing casts into the picture. For instance:

```
object a = 0xFF;
var z = (string)a;  // compiles but fails at runtime!
```

In the example above, the IDE will dutifully report that the type of `var z` is `System.String` - but this is, of course, entirely wrong.

Comment: I do use the var method, it's pretty handy. I guess as of now, there's probably no simple way to do what I want to do apart from checking with the specs or writing a test for an expression.

Comment: and @blizpasta the reason the hover your mouse over the keyword var works is because it is type referencing from short.  There is no need to hover over anything, just read (short) and know that is an Int16.

Comment: @Lucas B: you're right. var i = 0xFF; will be a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague on what you are looking for, so I don't know if "improved" intellisense solves it, but I would try the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef).